# Allow users to update my mobile app, but stop new downloads

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

I have an application on appstore and also in google play.
I want the current users to be able to update the application, but want to prevent further downloads to it.
Can this be achieved?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the app from sale in all countries where the app was never previously downloaded.

Set the price to $799, and say "Don't buy me! No refunds!" in the app store descriptions.  Remove anything in the description that might tempt somebody to buy it.  Remove all keywords (in the next update, if needed) to make it hard to find.  Rename the app in the app store to something obscure if possible (but leave the name under the icon the same).  None of the above should affect the ability of current users to download a new update if you get one approved and in the store.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible (on the AppStore) and I don't think it's on Google Play either.

If you want to freeze a version of your app and make a new "branch". A solution could be to create a new App with a new Bundle ID. Then the old app can still live in the App Store.

I don't know what you want to achieve from this and if Apple will approve it, but if you want to do this, Apple surely wants to see additional features or changes in the new version in order for it to be approved and not just an exact copy with a new Bundle ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your point. The released version has bugs and it is not free. I want to support current users, but do not want to allow new users as I want to re-release the application free but with in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is normally not possible using the Play Store.

Here are some very dirty solutions for Android (I would prefer method 1):

**1. Using Google Play:** Let all current users enter a private Google group (Or Google+ group) and publish your app only as Alpha or Beta. This way only users in the private group can update or download your app. New users won't see the app in the Play Store and won't be able to download it.

**2. Using Shared Preferences:** Let all users update the app and set a boolean in a Shared Preferences file. Then publish the new app which should not be downloadable by new users, and check if the boolean is set. If the boolean is not set close or kill the app and notify the user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but it is not suitable for my situation. It seems I will have to keep the application live.